# Smooth all data-points in a chart in nodejs/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, bezier, smoothing

I have a chart which line I wish to be able to make as smooth as possible. The line should still keep the overall pattern and as close to the original line as possible - but I need to be able to smooth all "bumbs" 100% away / to the degree I wish.

When I say "100% smooth" - I mean something like this (try to draw a curved line in the square): http://soswow.github.io/fit-curve/demo/

The line must only go up or down (while the main trend is up/down-wards) - E.g. like a Sine curve. Now imaging you added a lot of noise/bumps of different sizes/freq. to the Sine curve - but you like to "restore" the curve without changing the curve's overall pattern. That is exactly my need. The ideal: If I could filter away exactly the selected level of noise/freq. I wish to remove from the main trend.

SMA is lagging in nature and I need something which is a lot closer to the actual data-points in time.
I know the lagging feature of SMA is normally accepted - but I don't accept it ;) I strongly believe it would be possible to do better than that :) DMA can shift the data-points itself - but has no effect of the data-points info in real time which is what I'm looking for as well...I know I have to hack/compensate - and I can also come up with 100s of ways myself (mixing all the algos I know, running them multiple times etc.) But I guess someone out there is way smarter than me and that it has already been solved - and I would definitely wonder if not a standard algorithm for exactly this issue exist?

I have looked into many different algorithms - but none of them worked satisfyingly (Moving Averages, Median, polynomial regression, Savitzky Golay etc.). But the result is still way too "bumby" and "pixelated" and otherwise it again becomes too lagging.

Lastly I have found: Bezier Cubic and quadratic which seems pretty interesting but I don't know how apply it on all my data-points and I can't find a suitable NPM (I can only find libraries like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bezier-easing which only takes 1 data-point which is not what I'm looking for).

Savitzky G. is better than regular MA - but I still believe it lags too much when it is as smooth as I consider acceptable.

The task is pre-processing and noise-reduction of temperature, price and similar charts in real-time before it is handled over to an IA which looks for abnormalizes (too much noise seems to confuse the AI and is also unnecessary for the most parts). The example with the drawing was only an example - just as well as me mentioning a "Sine curve" (to illustrate my point). The chart is in general very arbitrary and doesn't follow any pre-defined patterns.

I like to emphasize again that the primary prerequisite of the selected algorithm/procedure must be - that it generates a chart-line which minimizes lagging from the main chart's overall trend to an absolutely minimum and at the same time makes it possible to adjust at what level the noise-reduction should take place :-)

I have also made this small drawing in paint - just so you easily would understand my point :-) [screencast.com/t/jFq2sCAOu](https://screencast.com/t/jFq2sCAOu) The algo should remove and replace all instances/areas in a given chart which matches the selected frequency - in the drawing is only shown one of each - but normally there would exist many different areas of the chart with the same level of noise.

Please let me know if all this makes sense to you guys - otherwise please pin-point what I need to elaborate more about.

All help, ideas and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The question is too unspecific and isn't suitable for SO. It lacks the context, it's unclear if you need to do this for artistic purpose or scientific. Moving averages, etc are perfectly suitable for data graphs. You miss the point of bezier. It can provide missing data points, not replace existing ones. Replacing them is basically vector tracing, which is complex, primarily artistic task and not used for graphs.

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic on SO. If you provide a specific implementation then it can be discussed and improvements can be suggested. I believe the problem you describe can be easily solved without a specific support for 'center line' in a filter.

Comment: The lag you talk about is natural for filtering. Moving average, etc are commonly used for price data, a lag is perceived as normal there. You can try to compensate for it (it's called displaced moving average), try to add additional leading data points (1/2 window size) and remove them then, or use two-step filtering and reverse data for the first step. DSP offers a bigger choice of filters that may have more desirable characteristics but all of them naturally introduce a delay they needs to be compensated in your case and may not work well if the number of data points is low.

Comment: Moving average is pretty much standard, the lag makes sense for time series because time is unidirectional. What was the problem with Savitzky-Golay? It's a well-suited solution from DSP perspective, I'd expect it to be fine. Your perception of proper smoothed graph may differ from what smoothed representation of data may actually look like.

Comment: Before anyone can answer this, you really do need to [be more precise](/help/how-to-ask) about what data you have, and what you meant with 100% smooth. Just a drawing app is not good enough: show _your_ data (e.g. show a plot of a representative sample), and show what you consider "100% smooth" for that data. Also please explain what the "chart" you have represents and what you're trying to actually do to it (e.g. are you trying to abstract a vector outline of a hand-drawn shape, like the example app? Are you trying to find an outline, matched to within some error distance? etc)

Comment: Note that you've put _way too much in comments_ by now. Update your post, [put all these details there](/help/how-to-ask). Comments are not where you introduce new information, it's where you say you updated your post with new information. Someone else looking at this tag shouldn't need to read "a post plus a book's worth of comments" before they understand what you need help with =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have now updated the main post :-) Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: @Garfield2021 As said, this may be artistic task and not scientific, so algo results may differ greatly from how you'd draw a perfectly smooth envelope by hand. IIRC Savitzky-Golay shouldn't cause time shifts, if it's different in your case an example could be helpful. What you drawing shows is that you want to remove high frequency noise but keep transients (extremum points) intact. But transients also high freq, by using a filter you inevitably smudge them, this needs to process data with some kind of DSP before feeding to it to S-G for extra smoothing.

Comment: Can't can't say which DSP exactly but at this point it's not much different from other task like audio processing. I guess S-G is the best or close to what you can get without going too deep. Check https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ is you're serious about scientific part. This is not a regular task by any means and you shouldn't expect that a ready to use solution exists (although it's not impossible). If you want to approach it from artistic side, this may be very different, probably AI-based solutions exist to vectorize a curve (they aren't specific to graphs, actually XY graphs may look odd).